# One number is a multiple of other

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let $$S \subset N_{100}= \{1,2,3,4, \dots, 100 \}$$ with $|S|=51$.
Then prove for any such $S$ it is possible to select two numbers from $S$ such that one is a multiple of other.

I wasn't able to proceed. How should I start.
I think it needs Pigeon Hole Principle.

Comment: I added the final $100$ in the list of elements of $N_{100}$. This is absolutely necessary for the question to make sense. Note that the notation $N_{100}$ is **not** standard, so a precise description must be given. Leaving those three dots/ellipsis at the end of the list conveys the intent that the list will continue indefinitely.

Comment: For the record, I also support closing this question for lack of context. Saying that you "don't know how to start" is not sufficient context. You were given related example problems with absolute certainty.

Comment: Yeah, ,that other question answers this perfectly.